# Sencha Cordova app not working for version less than 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am making a sencha app using 
`sencha app build native`
its working for 4.4 or higher version of android. but not working for less than 4.4 version. I am naive to android so don't know what mistake i am doing or in sencha project i need to set out the `minApiVersion`
I tried setting the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />` in AndroidManeifest.xml once it built it for targetSdkVersion19 and again building it. But thats also not helping.

Comment: post your logcat i am thinking of missing support libraries.

Comment: I will be doing that but i wonder when i do sencha app build native buy default its setting my targetSdkVersion to 19. Where it is being set?

Comment: @android_Muncher below are the logcat.
[ 08-21 06:47:19.241 14905:14905 D/CordovaLog ]
file:///android_asset/www/app.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_incr_' of undefin

[ 08-21 06:47:19.241 14905:14905 E/Web Console ]
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_incr_' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:1

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem which i was facing is EXTJS 6.0 does support only 4.4+ native android.And i checked with Sencha guys they don't have any plans to support less than 4.4.